# HOw can i overcome The SQL query exceeded the maximum number of joins. The allowed limit is 5 error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I wrote a query to fetch customer as below .

```
SELECT customer
FROM catalog join industry in catalog.Industy  
join category in industry.Category   
join Subcategory in category.Subcategory
join product in Subcategory.Product
join MethodOfPreparation in product.MethodOfPreparation 
join customer in MethodOfPreparation.Customer
```

but ,i got the following error

> The SQL query exceeded the maximum number of joins. The allowed limit is 5

How can i solve this. please any one help me?

Comment: Maybe you could use a temporary table to store some of the joins, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-temporary).

Comment: You are missing the `ON` clause for your `JOIN` statements. Perhaps that's the issue rather than the number of `JOINs`.

Comment: On case it did not get you please give me a sample

Comment: i am execute this query in cosmos db ,can i able to use temporary table there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such temp table could be used in cosmos db SQL query. According to this [official blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/documentdb-raises-sql-query-limits/), the limit will not be increased for the time being.

I suggest you split the query SQL or adjust the data structure. After all, too many join times could also reduce query efficiency.

Surely, you could submit your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to improve the features of COSMOS DB.

---

For example,my data looks like:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "a": [
        {
            "b": [
                {
                    "c": [
                        {
                            "d": [
                                {
                                    "e": [
                                        {
                                            "f": [
                                                {
                                                    "g": "AAA"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My SQL could be like below to avoid over 5 join times:

```
SELECT e.f
FROM root r
join a in r.a  
join b in a.b   
join c in b.c
join d in c.d
join e in d.e
```

If you want to query the sub property in the `e.f` (for your SQL is `MethodOfPreparation.Customer`), you could loop the result in the stored procedure to put items into an output array.

---

Update:

If you want to filter `customer.id` finally, I suggest you query the customer array firstly by normal SQL:

```
SELECT MethodOfPreparation.customer
FROM catalog join industry in catalog.Industy  
join category in industry.Category   
join Subcategory in category.Subcategory
join product in Subcategory.Product
join MethodOfPreparation in product.MethodOfPreparation
```

Then use code to loop the array in stored procedure in cosmos db:

```
var returnArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){

   var customer = feed[i];
   //to judge if id meets the filter condition
   if(id==???){
      returnArray.push(customer);
   }
}
```

Comment: How can i split the query ? please any idea

Comment: @iamthiru I mean for example,you could query the sql with 5 join in the stored procedure,then use code to loop the query result to get the `customer` in every item.

Comment: @iamthiru Yes,f is array. Then can't use sql, use code to loop the result and add every f.id into an output array. That's my idea.

Comment: @iamthiru Anyway,my word is you can't implement all your need in one single query. You could use sql plus code to combine the final result.

Comment: @iamthiru Sure,any concern,please let me know.

Comment: for example , i need to get all by customer id

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SQL  View
 It will help to join more table as well as return more columns.

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CustomerView] AS
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot use more then 5 join in a single query as stated in microsoft docs. Please find this link for more info. [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits)
[image]

For now you may optimize your join by dividing them into sub query.